# jQuery ".length" + checkboxes confusing

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a form with "[iCheck](http://icheck.fronteed.com/)" checkboxes and want to check how many checkboxes are checked. iCheck has (amongst others) the callbacks "ifChecked" and "ifUnchecked" that I use for this. The problem is: When I check the first checkbox ("Apple") I get a "0" - when I click "Apple" again I get a "1" - so I am not able to correctly work with the "length" function in that example. Any idea what to do here?

The background is that I want to first hide the "basket" and then show the basket hen there are at least 1 or max. 3 fruits checked. When the user selects 4 or more fruits I want to hide the basket again.

Here is a [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/herrfischer/pen/gXeOmy)

```
$('.my_cool_form input').on('ifChanged', function() {
  if ($('.my_cool_form .checked').length == 0 ) {
$('.info').addClass('active');
  }
  if ($('.my_cool_form .checked').length == 3 ) {
    $('.info').removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

Comment: try replace `.checked` with `:checked` like https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vWRqXj

Comment: There is a small syntax error in your code. The quotation sign at `<input name="email"-b value="b" type="checkbox">`is misplaced ;-)

Comment: I don't know the plugin, but how about `var string = $('.my_cool_form .checked').length+1;`??

Comment: Why should it matter to use ":checked" over ".checked"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***This will work for you:***

Just change your `$('input').on('ifChanged', function()` to

```
// show checked elements
$('input').on('ifChanged', function() {                             
    var string = $('.my_cool_form input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
    $('.jQuery_length_info span').text(string);
});
```

I have also added a `load` function:

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
  if ($('.my_cool_form input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length < 3 ) {
      $('.info').addClass('active');
  }
  else{
      $('.info').removeClass('active');
  }

});
```

*to check the checkbox on load*

I tried this in **your codepen** all it worked fine for me.

*A working [**codepen**](https://codepen.io/Jithinraj7/pen/GOxbxz) for you, hope this was helpfull for you.*

Answer (score 1):

You can simply verify all your checked checkboxes with the [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector :

```
$('.my_cool_form input').on('ifChanged', function() {
    if ($('.my_cool_form input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length < 3 ) {
        $('.info').addClass('active');
    }
    else{
        $('.info').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```